# What are the parameters for the approveAndCall function in tokens?

Tags: erc-20

Can somebody please explain what the paramters are in the function `approveAndCall` that is used in some ERC-20 tokens?

```
function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes32 data) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`approveAndCall` is a function that combines approving a `spender` contract to transfer some amount of tokens, and calling a function of that `spender`.

The amount of tokens that the spender is allowed to spend, is provided in the `tokens` parameter. The `data` parameter is used to provide the spender any additional data with which it can decide what specific actions to take.

Comment: Thanks a lot this help me alot can u tell me more about data parameter what actually i have to pass because when i pass the data fox ex : hello it seems to show error / and when i pass a hex data then it shows gas estimation error